# Azure Functions V4 .NET 7 Programmatically get the Default/Master Key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

i am having trouble getting the Azure Functions Keys Programmatically. I am aware i could simply use the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` But this would mean having to manually update the configuration each time i renew the key. Furthermore, i cannot use any type of Authentication Provider (Micro, Google etc) at this current time. Currently i managed to get it working locally using the following code, but when i Publish this to Azure it causes a **EnvironmentCredential auth Exception** Is there an alternative way or how can i alter what i have to achieve my goal?

```
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
        var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
        var webSitesEnumerator = subscription.GetWebSitesAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (await webSitesEnumerator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var webSite = webSitesEnumerator.Current;
                var hostKeys = await webSite.GetHostKeysAsync();
                var defaultKeyItem = hostKeys.Value.FunctionKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == DefaultKey);
                return defaultKeyItem.Value;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await webSitesEnumerator.DisposeAsync();
        }
```

The error is as follows

```
Result: Exception when Authenticating User.Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
```

- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

Comment: What is the exact error (type, message, stack trace)? Side note: consider `await foreach`.

Comment: Updated post with error as requested

Comment: When running in the cloud, `DefaultAzureCredential` works best with [managed Azure identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

Comment: i have created a managed azure identity and assigned it but still getting the same error

Comment: Have you checked that your `Azure.Identity` package is the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and used an alternative way to get/ retrieve function key using Rest api:

You can make use of this [**Azure Rest API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-function-keys) in your .Net 7.0 Function to get the function key:-

**My httpTrigger .net 7.0 Isolated Function:-**

**Funtion.cs:-**

```c
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var token = await GetAccessToken("<Tenant-Id>", "<Client-ID>", "<Client-Secret>");
            var results = await GetResults(token);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            await response.WriteStringAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results));

            return response;
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientKey);
            var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }), default);
            return result.Token;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetResults(string token)
        {
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/");

            string subscriptionId = "0151c97cb2a7";
            string resourceGroupName = "name of resource group";
            string name = "Function App name";
            string functionName = "Function Name";
            string apiVersion = "2022-03-01";

            string URI = $"{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}/listkeys?api-version={apiVersion}";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, null);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var httpResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return httpResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the error response here
                return "Error: " + response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My function.csproj file:-**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
```

Make sure the service principal Client ID and Client Secret is correct and it has appropriate contributor role to Read the Function Key for the above API to work.

**Output:-**

[image]

**Function key retrieved:-**

[image]